# Page_load in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In asp.net, when working on web app, there is a function called 'Page_Load', which is empty. Is this called everytime the page is loaded? What if I remove this function? Essentially what is the main purpose of Page_Load?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Google is your friend:  http://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+page+load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its main purpose it to do / verify / check things when the page is loading ( one of its start events).

this function is being called by reflection when `AutoEventWireup` is on.